# Local gulp not found windows

Tags: git, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have created a Yeoman Project in Mac and its was perfect, and I did a push in my repository.

In another place, in a windows Pc, I did a git clone of this project, but first I installed in the folder:

```
npm install -g yo gulp bower
```

And

```
npm install -g generator-gulp-angular
```

But it show a error when I do a gulp serve or excute gulp:

```
C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\yeoman\PruebaYeoman\app>gulp serve
[19:49:44] Local gulp not found in ~\Desktop\yeoman\PruebaYeoman\app
[19:49:44] Try running: npm install gulp
```

Also I can see that the folder bower_components are not up in the repository.. not up with git push.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `bower install` and `npm install` manually before trying to run gulp?

Comment: Oh yeah, its this, I must run it. Thank